# Cauchy criterion problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Suppose that $\{x_m\}$ is a sequence of positive, non-zero numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x_n}$ diverges, and let $S_n = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$. Moreover, suppose that for all $m \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{x_{m + j}}{S_{m + j}} \geq 1 - \frac{S_m}{S_{m + n}}$. Use the Cauchy criterion to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{S_n}$ diverges.

I'm not very sure how to tackle this problem. I somewhat understand how to approach it but I'm unsure how the formal proof would look like. Any hints or assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{S_n}$ is convergent. Let's write out the Cauchy criterion: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be any number less than $1$ (if you want you can fix e.g. $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$). Then there is some natural number $N$ such that for all $m\geq N,k\geq 1$ we have $$\sum_{j=m+1}^{k+m}\frac{x_j}{S_j}<\varepsilon$$
By shifting indices we get: $$1-\frac{S_m}{S_{m+k}}\leq\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{x_{j+m}}{S_{j+m}}<\varepsilon$$
Now what happens if we let $k\to\infty$?

Comment: On second thought, do we reach a contradiction because $\epsilon > \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{x_{m + j}}{S_{m + j}} \geq 1$?

Comment: That is the idea, but we don't have $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{m+j}}{S_{m+j}}\geq1$. However by the chain of inequalites we get for all $k\geq1$ $$1-\frac{S_m}{S_{m+k}}<\varepsilon<1$$ and this will be the contradiction since $S_{m+k}\to+\infty$ and therefore $1-\frac{S_m}{S_{m+k}}\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$.